# reset kafka-connector source offset to 0

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a bunch of Kafka JDBC source connectors; I need to re-key one of them. I've deleted the topic and deleted/re-created the connector with new config, but am having issues getting the topic offset for the source connector reset such that it will re-pull the source data from the database. I do not want to rename the connector as I only need to do this on one or two of many clients and i want the naming to be consistent.  I was thinking I could do something with connect-offsets but am not having much luck.

Any ideas or pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: I vaguely remember there being a Confiuent blog post about doing JDBC connector offset manipulation

Comment: @OneCricketeer I think the blog entry in question might be this? https://confluent.jp/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#resetting

Comment: Potential duplicate, with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66427647/how-do-we-reset-the-state-associated-with-a-kafka-connect-source-connector/66427827#66427827