# How do we reset the state associated with a Kafka Connect source connector?

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

We are working with [Kafka Connect](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/index.html) 2.5.

We are using the [Confluent JDBC source connector](https://docs.confluent.io/kafka-connect-jdbc/current/source-connector) (although I think this question is mostly agnostic to the connector type) and are consuming some data from an IBM DB2 database onto a topic, using 'incrementing mode' (primary keys) as unique IDs for each record.

That works fine in the normal course of events; the first time the connector starts all records are consumed and placed on a topic, then, when new records are added, they are added to our topic. In our development environment, when we change connector parameters etc., we want to effectively *reset* the connector on-demand; i.e. have it consume data from the “beginning” of the table again.

We thought that deleting the connector (using the [Kafka Connect REST API](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/connect/references/restapi.html#delete--connectors-(string-name))) would do this - and would have the side-effect of deleting all information regarding that connector configuration from the Kafka Connect `connect-*` metadata topics too.

However, this doesn’t appear to be what happens. The metadata remains in those topics, and when we recreate/re-add the connector configuration (again using the REST API), it 'remembers' the offset it was consuming from in the table. This seems confusing and unhelpful - deleting the connector doesn’t delete its state. Is there a way to more permanently wipe the connector and/or reset its consumption position, short of pulling down the whole Kafka Connect environment, which seems drastic? Ideally we’d like not to have to meddle with the internal topics directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer to this question: it seems the behaviour we are seeing [is to be expected](https://confluent.jp/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/):

> If you’re using incremental ingest, what offset does Kafka Connect
> have stored? If you delete and recreate a connector with the same
> name, the offset from the previous instance will be preserved.
> Consider the scenario in which you create a connector. It successfully
> ingests all data up to a given ID or timestamp value in the source
> table, and then you delete and recreate it. The new version of the
> connector will get the offset from the previous version and thus only
> ingest newer data than that which was previously processed. You can
> verify this by looking at the offset.storage.topic and the values
> stored in it for the table in question.

At least for the Confluent JDBC connector, there is a [workaround to reset the pointer](https://confluent.jp/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-jdbc-source-connector/#resetting).

Personally, I'm still confused why Kafka Connect retains state for the connector at all when it's deleted, but seems that is designed behaviour. Would still be interested if there is a better (and supported) way to remove that state.

Another related blog article: https://rmoff.net/2019/08/15/reset-kafka-connect-source-connector-offsets/